# Anaconda worker does not start in Sublime text (Conncetion to local host timing out)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublime-anaconda

The following was the error I got

Sublime Text

IDAnaconda worker could not start because:

```
 connection to localhost:63828 timed out after 0.2s. tried to 
 conned 7 times during 2.0 seconds

 check that there is Python process executing the anaconda 
 jsonserver.py script running in your system. If there is check 
 that you can connectto your localhost writing the following 
 script in your Sublime Text 3 console:

 import socket; socket.socket(socket.AF_INEL 
 socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((iocalhost; 63828))

 If anaconda works just fine after you received this error and 
 the command above worked you can make anaconda to do 
 not show you this error anymore setting the 
 'swallow_startup_errors' to 'true' in your configuration file.
```

Kindly help me out here.

Comment: Have you performed the steps that the error message suggested? Is there a `jsonserver.py` script running? What happened when you ran that code (without spelling errors, all on one line) in the console?

Comment: I have performed the steps that error message suggested and looked around on other forums for relevant answers but couldn`t find any. There is no jsonserver.py script running. This error pops up right when I open sublime text regardless of running a code but it can be closed. I have not faced any other errors due to a consequence of this later while I was writing scripts. I was curious to know why it is happening.

Comment: Same error over here...

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it in my environment changing the default Anaconda Python interpreter from `python` to `python3`. To do that, go to Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > "Settings - Default" > `"python_interpreter": "python3",` (line ~100).