# Anaconda gives an error in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, sublimetext3

I installed Anaconda for Sublime Text 3 and after the installation it gives me the following error:

> Anaconda worker could not start because: connection to localhost:52847
> timed out after 0.2s. tried to connect 7 times during 2.0 seconds
> check that there is Python process executing the anaconda
> jsonserver.py script running in your system. If there is, check that
> you can connect to your localhost writing the following script in your
> Sublime Text 3 console: import socket; socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
> socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect(("localhost", 52847)) If anaconda works
> just fine after you received this error and the command above worked
> you can make anaconda to do not show you this error anymore setting
> the 'swallow_startup_errors' to 'true' in your configuration file.

Autocompletion doesn't works too.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it in my environment changing the default Anaconda Python interpreter from `python` to `python3`. To do that, go to Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > "Settings - Default" > `"python_interpreter": "python3"`, (line ~100).

PS: this appears to be a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815280/anaconda-worker-does-not-start-in-sublime-text-conncetion-to-local-host-timing/71355045#71355045).

Comment: This approach fixes my same issue too.